# How to access applicationContext from a Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using a Spring MVC Project from Netbeans and I've moved the applicationContext.xml file to /src/conf because I've read WEB-INF isn't the correct folder. I can't access to the application context from a controller in /src/java/web/controller. I've tried several ways and it doesn't deploy the project.

I would like a link to learn more about paths in a web project, pleas.

I think this could help us to figure out:

```
public class TasksController implements Controller {
private TaskManager taskManager;
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

public TaskController() {
    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");    
    taskManager = (TaskManager)context.getBean("taskManager");
}

@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.info("Returning view from TaskController");

    Map<String,Object> tasks = new HashMap<String,Object>();

// Get tasks from model

    return new ModelAndView("tasks","tasks",tasks);
}
```

Bye!

Comment: and what's the path? because the controller doesn't find the applicationContext in /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to create a TasksController to show the tasks in a JSP. I've got a bean taskManager defined in applicationContext.xml and I want the controller to get the taskManager and get the tasks with getTasks().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ouch.  OK, you don't instantiate new contexts from within your controller.  The context has already been configured by Spring, you just have to ask Spring for it.

Make your controller implement `BeanFactoryAware`, and Spring will then inject the context for you by automatically calling `setBeanFactory`:

```
public class TasksController implements Controller, BeanFactoryAware {
  private TaskManager taskManager;

  public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory context) {
     taskManager = (TaskManager)context.getBean("taskManager");
  }

  // handleRequest as before
}
```

Comment: Should do I inject the bean taskManager to TaskController in dispatcher-servlet.xml?